# New modulo operator

Tags: spacing, math-operators, size

I am trying to define new operator %. I tried to make it smaller but it also made spacing around it smaller. How can I reduce operator size without changing spacing around operator? 
Thanks for help guys

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand{\modd}{\mathsmaller{\mathbin{\%}}}
\begin{document}
$ x \modd y $
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd say you want `\mathbin{\mathsmaller{\%}}`

Comment: @egreg The problem with that approach is it produces a big `%` when used in `\displaystyle`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I use the star from of `\DeclareMathOperator`, so that displaystyle sub/super-scripts are above and below the operator (if needed).  Use without the `*` if you want the subscript to remain as a subscript in style, rather than below the operator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\modd}{\scriptstyle\%}
\begin{document}
$ x \modd y $
\[ x \modd y \]
$ x \modd_1 y $
\[ x \modd_1 y \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need it to work in the smaller math styles, then

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\modd}{%
  \mathchoice{\scriptstyle\%}{\scriptstyle\%}{\scriptscriptstyle\%}{\scriptscriptstyle\%}}
```

Comment: The spacing is incorrect; try `$a\modd(b+c)$`

Comment: @egreg Thanks for snatching defeat from the jaws of victory `8^b`

Answer (score 1):

You want to reverse the roles of `\mathbin` and `\mathsmaller`:
However, `\mathsmaller` has to be used with care.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand{\modd}{\mathbin{\mathchoice
  {\textstyle\mathsmaller{\%}}
  {\mathsmaller{\%}}
  {\mathsmaller{\%}}
  {\mathsmaller{\%}}
}}

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle x \modd y $

$ x \modd y $

$\scriptstyle x \modd y $

$\scriptscriptstyle x \modd y $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `\[ x \modd y \]`